# glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL) does not work properly

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I need to draw an object with triangles and a sphere. My object has its own material properties that I define them with glMaterialfv. Sphere is just a sphere with a color. However, some part of my object(it is one of its polygons) is colored with sphere's color. How can I solve this problem?

my object function

```
void drawObject()
{glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);




    for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
    {   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glNormal3f(..);
        glVertex3f(..);

        glNormal3f(..);
        glVertex3f(..);

        glNormal3f(..);
        glVertex3f(..);

        GLfloat ambientValues[]={..};
        GLfloat specularValues[]={..};
        GLfloat diffuseValuse[]={..};
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT,ambientValues);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE,diffuseValues);
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR,specularValues);


        glEnd();

    }




}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes here: Materials muse be set before the drawing operation. And `glMaterialfv` is not valid within a glBegin/glEnd block. BTW, you shouldn't use immediate mode (glBegin/glEnd) in the first place. Its use has been discouraged for well over 15 years now.

Comment: thanks a lot, when I set materials before the drawing operation, problem has been solved.